# running python in vim

Tags: 12.04, python, vim

I have tried Googling but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Is it possible to program in Python on VIM and do something like

```
:!iPython
```

to have Python execute the code?

Last time I tried that, it just opened up Python in the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the current buffer with `:w`, then `:!/usr/bin/env python %`.

Comment: Then that will execute the program or the command in the shell whichever I have written?

Comment: It will run the file you are currently editing (presumably a Python program) in Python. Give it a try.

Comment: I just tried it.  It executed and then said hit enter to return.  So everything went through but python didn't come up and show anything.

Comment: now I am receiving invalid syntax errors for something I ran yesterday with no problems.  Is there anything that needs to be setup in /.vimrc for this to work?

Comment: No. If you are receiving invalid syntax errors, it's probably because you have invalid Python syntax. Nothing about how vim is configured will impact that.

Comment: It can't be so though.  I ran this yesterday in Python and it worked.  It only doesn't work in Vim.

Comment: Here is the error:                                                                                                                              File "hw6problem2.py", line 14
    a0 = max(s/2, (s - c)/2)
     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    shell returned 1

Comment: Check the line before that one. I can tell you for sure that this is a different problem and has nothing to do with this method of invoking python from vim, which is working fine as evidenced by the fact that python is running your program. Run the program yourself from the command line and see what happens

Comment: Perhaps if your problem persists you can open up a new question on stackoverflow?

Comment: I asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672250/running-python-on-vim)

Answer (score 2):

or even better `set aw` in your .vimrc, follow by

```
:pyf %
```

this will not incur you to bring up shell and hence better.

if you want you can map it and save in your .vimrc following cmd

```
map <F8> pyf %<CR>
```

hitting F8 will execute your python file

Comment: This is not quite the same as using `/usr/bin/env python` - `:pyf` will always use `/usr/bin/pythonX` (depending on python3 vs python2).